# Android WebView - downloading PDF ends up with HTML file

Tags: android, webview, download

I try to download a PDF file from a webpage. But when I do so, I end up getting only a HTML file because the login isn't working for the download.

The link I try to load looks something like this:

https://somePage.de/auth/1%3A1%3A1026071014%3A3%3A0%3Aserv%3Ax/aufgaben/aufgabe3.pdf

Resolved it should look like this:

https://somePage.de/auth/1:1:1:122452345:4:4:serv:x/aufgaben/aufgabe3.pdf

The download is done by the Downloadmanager:

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
                Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/", url.length())));
                _DownloadManager.enqueue(request);

            } else
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
```

Is there something I miss here? Maybe some sort of config in the WebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution. Problem was, that the downloadmanager had no login state from the webview.
The solution to this is to give the request your cookie. Here the code (just two more lines):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (url.contains(".pdf")) {

        String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/", url.length())));
        request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        _DownloadManager.enqueue(request);

    } else
        view.loadUrl(url);

    return true;
}
```